# Log into the Windows event log with Log4j 2

Tags: java, windows, logging, log4j2, event-log

I'm actually working on a java project and as it seems to be realy powerful compared to Log4j 1.x I would like to use Log4j 2.

But I have a doubt and I can't seem to find any information about it :

Will I be able to log to the Windows event log with log4j 2, and if not natively, is there an external library compatible with log4j 2 that could help me do it?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one at the moment. It would be great if you could contribute one!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I have currently no time to work on that by myself but I think the old log4jna project could be a good basis to start working. (https://github.com/dblock/log4jna)